# How to retrieve data from db in a desired format (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem in retrieving data from db in a desired format. I have used PHP MYSQL. I am able to retrieve the records using `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result));` and so on... but not in a format as I want.

suppose, from db I am getting 10 records as 1 to 10 vertically, but I want the following format using table.

```
1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 10
```

Note: No of records are dynamic in nature, and I want 4 columns in each row.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you use php for that? why you need it from mysql?

Comment: That should be handled _after_ retrieval. This is solely a view issue (and can be handled easily at this point).

Comment: SQL is not designed for data representation. Handle that in your logic

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with MySQL, MySQL isn't used to nicely display your data, it's only used for storing and retrieving your data.

What you need is the following, whereas the $array can be replaced with your data from the database:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    if(($i % 4) == 0 && $i != 0) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    echo '<td>';
        echo $array[$i];
    echo '</td>';
}
    echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: You need to open `<tr>` before the loop and close it afterwards.

Comment: @SubimalSinha no problem, but please mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

Having 4 records per row in the database is not changing anything. There's no such a feature in database because it serves no purpose and can be achieved using PHP instead. As stated in the comments databases are not designed for data representation.

You can instead retrieve those data and store them as group of fours later using a simple PHP script:

```
$i = 0;
$in = 0;
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($i%4) {
        $in++;
    }
    $array[$in][] = $result;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As **juergen d** said 
*SQL is not designed for data representation. Handle that in your logic*

So you can

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$i=0;

while($i < sizeof($array ) )
{
 if($i%4 ==0 && $i>0) echo "<br>";
  echo $array[$i++] ;
}
```

**NOTE** Replace `$array` with your array from DataBase

Comment: It's better to use the size of the array to determine how many loops it will make instead of hardcoding it, also a table is better to use to represent the data because with large numbers your columns may not be in the same line.

Comment: it was just to show that it shoul be done by php no in sql. aneways thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = ... your mysqli call that returns the data from mysql
$i = 0;
if ($data) {
    $HTML = '<table><tr>';
    foreach($data as $k => $v) {
         $HTML .= '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
         if ($i == 3) {
             $i = 0;
             $HTML .= '</tr><tr>';
         }
         $i++;
    }
    $HTML .= '</tr></table>';
    echo $HTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is full example :) .. You need to create table "Category" in MYSQL with "Cname" column

```
<?php 
    require 'ConnDB.php';
    $sql = "Select * From Category";
    $ResShowCateg = mysqli_query($conn_link, $sql); 

    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';

    for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($ResShowCateg); $i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ResShowCateg);
        if(($i % 3) == 0 && $i != 0){
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
        echo '<td>';
        echo $row["Cname"];
        echo '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';

    mysqli_close($conn_link);
?>
```